# Laravel relationship hasMany retorna un array vacío

Tags: laravel-8

Básicamente tengo una relación entre los modelos de Product, y de Image

Un producto puede tener múltiples imágenes, así que lo que estoy tratando de obtener es un array de productos, y dentro de cada producto, un array de imágenes. Algo mas o menos así:

```
{
  products: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'product name',
      images: [
        {
           img_url: 'some url',
           id: 1
        },
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

En la migración de la tabla productos tengo esto:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  (...)
});
```

En la migracion de imágenes:

```
Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();
  $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
  (...)
});
```

En el modelo Product:

```
public function images(){
  return $this->hasMany(Image::class, 'img_url', 'id');
}
```

Y por último, en el modelo Image:

```
public function product(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

Pero cuando intento hacer un select de productos con un query así, siempre devuelve un array de imágenes vacío adentro de cada producto:

```
$products = Product::select('name')->with('images')->paginate(10);
```

También intenté cambiar el "with" a "withCount", y el resultado de eso es0

Si alguien pudiera ayudar, lo agradecería mucho

Comment: *Basically, this is [es.so]*. Por favor traduce tu pregunta al castellano.

Comment: @BetaM ahí lo traduje, y vi en algún lugar de internet que se seleccionaban así las columnas, por eso lo paso como parametro en el modelo, pero igualmente no me funciona, con o sin eso

Comment: Cuando creas la relacion con las imágenes estás usando el campo 'img_url' que no es el campo indice por el que relacionas las dos tablas : "$this->hasMany(Image::class, 'img_url', 'id');" le estás pidiendo que te cree una relación entre img_url y el ID. Puedes ver la documentación en [https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final era una combinación de factores, por un lado limpié la cache y re-migré la base de datos (php artisan migrate:fresh --seed)

Y por otro lado, también estaba mal definida la relación en los modelos. Era simplemente:

```
public function images(){
  return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
}
```